# WebView wrap-content

Tags: android, webview

Is it possible to load a URL in a WebView and resize it to fit the screen? I mean I want to make the WebPage small so that the user doesn't need to scroll. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, zooming out too much is not something the user would like cause it'll reduce the legibility of the content.

I would suggest trying to set the zoom controls, however, I don't know if it'll work in 2.1.

```
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Hope this solves the problem as you now are giving user the control to change the zoom level.

Answer (score 18):

You can also try setting an layout algorithm for the same.It worked for me

```
webview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
```

Comment: This still crashes on android os version below 2.2.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5024

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me because it actually fits the page to the content. Some of the other solutions will technically work, but occasionally you will get a page loaded zoomed out unnecessarily far with extra space around the content. One thing to note is that LayoutAlgorithm was deprecated in versions after 2.2, but was then undeprecated in 4.0. That being said, it should still work in the sdks in between.

Comment: Please don't use this answer. This is deprecated in latest web-view code

Answer (score 17):

Set the initial scale to 1. It then zooms in to fill the screen. Haven't tested how this works on really tall web sites (blog posts with lots of comments for example) but it's working on a Droid X and an HTC Aria with a standard web page.

```
WebView.setInitialScale(1);
```

I'll continue testing with different web pages but so far this is the best solution I've got for this issue.

EDIT: Tested with an obscenely long web page on both Droid X and Aria and got positive results on both. Setting the initial scale to 0 seems to turn the whole thing off resulting in initial scale being 100. I'm happy with these results, hope this helps others struggling with this issue.

Comment: I had a very similar issue and this solution ending up working for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
wb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
wb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
webview_settings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview_settings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview_settings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried just calling [`WebView.zoomOut()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#zoomOut%28%29) repeatedly until it returns `false`?

Also, I would note that this technique you want to use really relies on the web page being quite short.  If the page is long and you zoom out to fit it entirely on screen, the user is going to need very good eye sight! ;)

Comment: hey thanx... havent checked it yet but i guess i will try it once im over with certain formalities here... Thanx a lot...

Answer (score 2):

I was able to contain the entire page in my view by doing the following. First set the width and height to wrap_content. Then setting the initial scale to one like this:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) currentActivity.findView(R.layout.web_view, R.id.webview);
webview.setInitialScale(1);
```

I found that I could get this to keep the width to the minimum necessary to display a readable font and then scroll along the y coordinate every time by doing the following.  First set both the height and width to wrap_content.  Then set the zoom density to far in your code like this:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) currentActivity.findView(R.layout.web_view, R.id.webview);
webview.getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
```

This is probably the better solution most of the time.  Consider how small the font would be if you displayed the following web page in its entirety:

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.setInitialScale(number);
```

where the higher 'number' is, the more zoomed in your page will be.  start with lower numbers ( like 10) and adjust to taste

Answer (score 1):

Use this code for resize your webview according to screen .

setScrollContainer(false);

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work in a dialog using WRAP_CONTENT for both dimensions of the WebView, unfortunately when the web page becomes too large the webview pushes all my other widgets off the screen.

Android's layout system is pretty damn unintuitive!

Comment: You cant say that! You have used WRAP_CONTENT, if u need it to stay the same size and not change according to the size of the webpage then why not define its height and width... This will AFAIK solve ur problem!