# How can I show a web page fitting in webview?

Tags: android

In my application, it has a webview and link buttons.
If I click on the button, webview loads the destination pages.

Some pages fit in webview and they look fine, but some are not.
In every loaded pages, they have this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.8">
```

so they should look all the same:(

What's wrong with my code?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private ActionBar mActionBar;
    private SimpleSideDrawer mNav;
    WebView myWebView;  

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        myWebView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        myWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("http://example-site.com/");          
        myWebView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
        myWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true); 
    }
}   


//This will be called when the button is clicked

public void loadThisUrl(String url) {
    mNav.closeLeftSide();
    mNav.closeRightSide();

    myWebView.loadUrl(url);
}
```

**UPDATE**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: For fitting Webpage inside Webview see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3916330/android-webview-webpage-should-fit-the-device-screen

Comment: @Sameer I tried that but it returns this error `PIC_WIDTH cannot be resolved to a variable`

Comment: can you post your xml for the webview?

Comment: @Shrikant Sure. I can't figure out how to define PIC_WIDTH

Comment: @Shrikant I added UPDATE to my question. Thanks

Comment: @Shrikant it does not related to XMl.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this for your webview

```
 <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```

Comment: did u try this webview..getSettings().setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);

Comment: do I need to write that only once within onCreate? or within loadThisUrl(String url) also?

Comment: it is a setting for your webview, so write it only once after this line
myWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);

Comment: i am too facing with the same issue but left this part out of my app so getting curious about it,
try WebView.setInitialScale(1); in java code 
or check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991219/webview-wrap-content