# Webview adding white space on right side

Tags: android, html, css, android-layout, android-webview

How to load a html content with fixed height and width into a android webview which has height and width set to wrap_content?
This is my HTML page i.e label.html loading from assets.

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>Untitled Document</title>
 <style>
 @charset "utf-8";
 /* CSS Document */
  .Main{
  width:50%;
  height:200px;
  border: 1px solid #09ED1C;
  float:left;
  background-color:#00F3FF;
  }
 H1{
 color:#FC1D21;
 }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="Main" align="center">
<h1>This page is created using internal CSS</h1>
</div>
</body>
</html>



<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/blue">

<WebView 
android:id="@+id/wv_help"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</RelativeLayout>

WebSettings webSettings = mWebViewHelp.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebViewHelp.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
mWebViewHelp.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/label.html");
```

This is adding white space on the right side of webview even though its wrap_content,WebView.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY is also not solving my issue,any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1991219/webview-wrap-content

Comment: why you are setting html page width 50%

Comment: html page height and width causes problem remove `width:50%;
  height:200px;`

Comment: @AkhileshPatil, it can be of any height and width.

Comment: simply remove `width:50%;  height:200px;` it wll automatically adjust in your view

Comment: use viewport property on html or on Webview setting   `webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);`

Comment: No,setting setUserWidePort to true also doesn't work, and i cant remove width and height , it(html) will come from server and can be of any height and width.

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira tried all properties , still no luck.

Comment: if your HTML contains height, width it automatically cover only height width area only

Comment: either if you want to remove white area you can set your webview backgound color transparent `mWebViewHelp.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Comment: Setting background color won't help.If my HTML content also has transparent color instead of  #FC1D21 ,it will set the background color to blue, which is parent relative layout's background color.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your HTML header:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

So it will look like this:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>[YOUR_DOCUMENT_NAME]</title>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>
```

I hope it works so not please respond

Comment: What do you see then? Can you give me some more info?

Comment: It looks like this [link](https://ibb.co/eC55wk) after adding meta tag also, If you can see the white color space on the right side

Comment: The white space on the right side is normal because you set the width on 50% but the with space on the left and on the top is not normal.

Comment: Yes , but that width and height can be anything.It will be a custom value.

Comment: So you want to get the with space on the top and on left away. So your background color is fulled to the top and to the left?

Comment: The space on the top and left side is fine, but i want to get rid of space on the right side. so that i can align the HTML content onto my WebView and align is anywhere.

Comment: If you set with 100% and align center everthing while be alined in the center in the middle of your webpage

Comment: as i said width ban be anything set on the HTML source.Android web view doesn't seem to support wrap_content width.Any hack that i can use for resizing the web view according to its HTML content.?